# Python: Strange behavior of locals()

Tags: python, locals

I am experiencing a strange behavior of a built-in function locals() in Python.  It is hard to explain exactly, but please take a look at a code:

```
def Main():
  def F(l=locals()):  print 'F', id(l), l
  a= 100
  F()
  print '1', id(locals()), locals()
  F()
```

In the local function `F`, I am assigning `locals()` into `l` as a default value for enclosure.  Since `locals()` is a `dict`, its reference is copied to `l`.  So the last three lines should have the same result.

However the result is like this:

```
F 139885919456064 {}
1 139885919456064 {'a': 100, 'F': <function F at 0x7f39ba8969b0>}
F 139885919456064 {'a': 100, 'F': <function F at 0x7f39ba8969b0>}
```

The three `print` statements are called at almost the same time, and `id` of `locals()` and `l` are the same, but the first `l` used in `F` does not have content.

I cannot understand why this happened.  Can anyone explain this phenomenon? Or is this a known/unknown bug?

Many thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't explain this phenomenon.  It is expected that ``l`` in ``F`` and ``locals()`` have the same id, but it is NOT expected that they do not have the same content.

Comment: if you call `locals()` inside of `F` you'd get a different result, but since all three calls to `locals()` is inside `Main` (because the definition is inside Main so the default argument is evaluated in that scope) They give the same dictionary

Comment: They are actually the same dictionary as their ids are the same.  However their contents are different.  That is the issue I cannot understand.

Comment: ok sorry for the confusion, you can get the same behaviour by just doing `saved = locals()` and printing it out later, no need to also add extra contexts to confuse (me) people. Retracting my close vote.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) for the `locals` function, you'll see

> **Update** and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.

`locals()` doesn't just return a dict of local variables; it also **updates** the dict to reflect current local variable values.

Comment: Now I clearly understand the above behavior.  I thought that similar to ``globals``, ``locals`` provides us a direct access to the dictionary of local variables.  Is there an alternative to directly access to the dictionary of local variables in a function?

Comment: @Akihiko: Local variables aren't actually implemented with a dict, so no.